# Vertical separation between paragraphs in the same bulletpoint in HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

I take notes in a plain text format and view them as HTML. When I write a list (whether ordered or unordered), sometimes I write two paragraphs in the same bulletpoint. In the HTML display, these paragraphs appear very close together. How can I modify the `.css` template file in order to increase the vertical separation between them?

I this is controlled by the elements `li`, `ol` and `ul` but I don't know how to tweak them exactly. The following is the current code for these elements.

```
p, table, ul, ol, dl {margin-top: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 1.5em;}
ul ul, ul ol, ol ol, ol ul {margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;}
li {margin: 1.5em auto; padding: 50px 0px;}
ul {margin-left: 2em; padding-left: 0.5em;}

ol {
  margin:0 0 1.5em;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:item;
}

ol>li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 2em;
  text-indent:-2em;
  list-style-type:none;
  counter-increment:item;
}

ol>li:before {
  display:inline-block;
  width:1.5em;
  padding-right:0.5em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:right;
  content:counter(item) ".";
}
```

Comment: Can you add example HTML to your question?

Comment: Hi. I don't know how to display HTML in the question itself, and I don't think I can add a screenshot because of my low score. Would you like a link to the HTML file itself?

Comment: Here is a description about how to add code to your answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I see, I didn't understand exactly what you meant. Just added the code for the list elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For separation between paragraphs in bullet points specifically:

nothing different just do this
for example:

```css
li + li{
  margin-top: 60px; /*as per requirement*/
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be </li>
  <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be </li>
</ol>
```

Also, there could be a future problem if you have many bullet lists in a page so
just make an id for your bullet list tag and you will be all set, for example:

```css
#first li + li{
  margin-top: 60px; /*as per requirement*/
}
```

```html
<ol id="first">
  <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be </li>
  <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that refers to the height of each line, i.e. to the vertical space between individual lines. However, I would like to add space between paragraphs, not between individual lines.

Comment: @mgarort I edited as per your requirement, hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I think though this will affect every paragraph? I would like to change the separation between paragraphs in bulletpoints specifically. Is this possible?

Comment: @mgarort there you go as you asked, hope it helps.